# setting a variable in a function in eLisp

Tags: function, lisp, elisp

Trying to pass a function and a list to a function.  Trying to compare each item in the list with the following item.

Function is:

```
(defun my-list-function(fn L)
    (if (< (length L) 2)
        (message "List needs to be longer than 2")
        (progn (setq newL L) ;; Save the list locally
               (while (> (length newL) 1)  ;; While list has 2 items
                      (setq t (car newL)) ;; Get first item
                      (setq newL (cdr newL)) ;; resave list minus first item
                      (funcall #'fn t #'car newL)))))  ;; pas first two items to a function
```

I keep getting an error - setting constant-t

Comment: When you want to have a local variable within a function, you usually bind it with [`let`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html) before using it. In this code sample, `newL` actually becomes a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t` is a reserved name (see [11.2 Variables that never change](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Constant-Variables.html#Constant-Variables)). Use instead of `t` a different variable name that tells what it contains/means (like for example `firstItem`).

Answer (score 1):

```
(setq newL L) ;; Save the list locally
```

This does not save *locally*. `newL` is not a local variable. `setq` does not declare local variables. `setq` sets variables to some value.

Comment: Voted up, though you should probably mention the solution as well :)